# Display Entire Album Art Lock Screen iOS 11

Tags: ios

So I have noticed that on iOS 11 my lockscreen displays like this now.

[image]

I would like to display the entire album art in full screen.  Is there a way to get the old behavior on the left maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No definitely not with out a jailbreak.  There are [several reddit threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/8qocfb/will_we_ever_get_large_album_artwork_on_our_lock/) about [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/71skg5/album_art_ios_11/).

Answer (score 0):

Ohh goshh.. Apple should definitely reconsider this and revert back to "show Album art".

Is there any way to raise "Feature request" (somewhere in apple forums)??